# None of the callback of Firestore.collection.document.set() is trigering

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a project that uses firestore but it is not setting the value of the document. Authentication is working fine but the `Firestore.collection.document.set()` is not working. here is the code I have tried

```
collectionReference.document(email).set(data).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
        auth.signOut();
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        startActivity(new Intent(SignUpRepActivity.this,LoginActivity.class));
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}).addOnCanceledListener(new OnCanceledListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCanceled() {
        Log.v("Cancelled","Cancelled");
    }
}).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        Log.v("Task","Complete");
    }
});
```

None of these callbacks are working and nothing in logs as well.

Comment: "is not working" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly doesn't work? Is any of the callbacks triggered?

Comment: .set function in first line is not working and it is mentioned in the questions that **None of these callbacks are working and nothing in logs as well.**

Comment: Are you then sure you have an internet connection on the user device?

Comment: Let's start at the beginning: is `data` written to your `email` document at all?

Comment: Yes because that is why Authentication is working

Comment: @b2m9 nothing literally nothing in firestore

Comment: Is your collection reference valid? Does _any_ write operation to Firestore succeed? Does a network request to Firestore even go out? If yes, what does the response contain?

Comment: Yes Reference is valid but none of the succeed and I do think that somehow request is not going out because after that line there is nothing in logs.

Comment: In case of invalid reference onFailure gets called

Comment: Well out of nowhere it is working now magically

Comment: how did you resolve the issue?

Comment: I actually had one `auth.signOut()` before this as well I removed that and it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

auth.signout() deletes the current registration token, clears the document folder on the device, and logs out the user. As confirmed by @Junaid Khalid,  by removing the auth.signout(), it is working fine now.